# Add data to new column in csv file with Javascript

Tags: javascript, csv

I want add data to new column in csv file. I using Javascript. I try with `'\r\n'` but not work. Comma make new row in same column.

```
for (var i = 0, l = mydata.length; i < l; ++i) {
    csvRows.push(mydata[i].join(','));
}
csvRows.push('\r\n'); //here want to go in second column
csvRows.push(mydata[0].join(',')); //this want write in second column first row
var csvString = csvRows.join("%0A");
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.href = 'data:attachment/csv,' + csvString;
a.target = '_blank';
a.download = 'file.csv';
document.body.appendChild(a);
a.click();
```

What I must push in `csvRows` to make new column? [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/nkm2b/222/) is similar example.

Comment: Looks like you need to loop through every thing in the array and add `, `. You just can't push something here.

Comment: And please complete all the incomplete codes! `csvRows`, `mydata`, `l`, etc.

Comment: @PraveenKumar I update question. In fiddle is similar example how it's work.

Comment: Check my answer. Gives you some idea.

Comment: I have updated my answer.

Comment: Did you find a workaround for excel? Looks like older version of excel only created a new column with ";", newer ones create with ","

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is specific when I open with Microsoft Excell. When I try with other programs, this works.

In Microsoft Excell work for me, if I change `,` to `;`

Comment: Boss you can set the tab delimiter for that.

Answer (score 2):

Let's try here:

```js
var data = [
  "Col1,Col2,Col3",
  "Col4,Col5,Col6"
];
console.log(data);
```

[image]

But if you wanna add one more column, you need:

```js
var data = [
  "Col1,Col2,Col3",
  "Col4,Col5,Col6"
];
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
  data[i] += ",NewCol" + (i + 1);
console.log(data);
```

[image]

Comment: I know what you mean, but I think, here is not this problem. Try in fiddle link write 5 numbers in one column, and next 5 in second column.

Comment: @neiiic Lemme check.

Comment: In JS is ok. I try in my code. Works too. But I think, the problem is in csv file. \n don't make me new column. Look here: http://jsfiddle.net/szqgy016/7/

Comment: @neiiic Right... Just revert back my code. I changed `a` with `div` and `\A0` with `<br />`...

Comment: @neiiic Mate, it works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/d465p9aw/ Check it out correctly.

Comment: wau interesting problem. I open in microsoft 2012 and I don't see changes in new columns. All in one column. I try with: https://sheet.zoho.com/sheet/excelviewer and see in new column things. Where you open?  Calc? And sorry for blaming.

Comment: @neiiic May be you forgot the `,`?

Comment: No. Because your link  http://jsfiddle.net/d465p9aw/ show me like this: http://imgur.com/fJBNIdd